# How to use application.propeties in spring cloud config client application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

How to use `application.yml` in spring cloud config client application?

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app-cli
  profiles:
    active: DEV
  config:
    import: "configserver:"
  cloud:
    config:
      name: ${spring.application.name}
      uri: http://192.168.0.12:8888
      username: thirumal 
      password: thirumal 
      request-read-timeout: 200
      request-connect-timeout: 100
      fail-fast: true
```

The client app is configure with all the required properties, still it's not connecting to `config-server`.

The lib `implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'`

Comment: Which `Spring` and `Spring Cloud` version are you using?

Comment: spring boot `2.5.4`

Comment: Spring Cloud version?

Comment: springCloudVersion `2020.0.3`

Comment: `bootstrap.properties` is working. but I don't want to use the legacy dependency `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap`. FROM Version 2.4.0, we can use `application.yml`

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/#config-data-import